# Error: no matching function for call to (unsolvable?)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I'm a c++ beginner. I'm attempting to instantiate three arrays of a class with a struct name as the template parameter. From there, I want to loop and call the mutator function to set the value in the array.

```
int main()
{
    GenericRecord<Furniture> furnObj[10][3];
    GenericRecord<Building> buildObj[10][3];
    GenericRecord<Computer> compObj[10][3];

    Building b;
    Furniture f;
    Computer c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the identifier for the furniture: ";
        cin >> f.Identifier;
        furnObj[i][0].setRecord(f.Identifier);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting a compiler error as follows:

> `error: no matching function for call to 'GenericRecord<Furniture>::setRecord(int&)'
>   note: candidate is:
>   note: void GenericRecord<Type>::setRecord(Type) [with Type = Furniture]`

I've tried to rework this 100 different ways, and I keep getting different kinds of compiler errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the template class, members, and structs:

```
struct Furniture
{
    int Identifier;
    string Description;
    float Value;
};

template <class Type>
class GenericRecord
{
    private:
        Type record;
    public:
        void setRecord(Type recParam);
};

template<class Type>
void GenericRecord<Type>::setRecord(Type recParam)
{
    record = recParam;
}
```

Comment: In your case `Type` is `Furniture` but you 're passing `f.Identifier` which is an `int`.

Comment: Instead of calling `furnObj[i][0].setRecord(f.Identifier);`, try `furnObj[i][0].setRecord(f);`

Comment: just read the error message. Says you have a function called `setRecord` that takes a `Type` as argument, but you are calling it with an int

Answer (score 1):

(If you're a C++ beginner, I don't think you should dive right into templates, but anyway...)

```
GenericRecord<Furniture> furnObj[10][3];
```

This creates an array of `GenericRecord` objects where Type = Furniture. Since Type = Furniture, that means that `setRecord(Type recParam)` expects to receive a Furniture object.

But you are calling `setRecord()` with `f.Identifier`, which is an int. That is the cause of the problem.